# Approach at designing ASP.NET Core 2 applications that share functionality

Tags: asp.net-core, architecture

Currently I've been tasked to create a bunch of small-to-medium applications, each of them having some common functionality.

1. Implement a preapproved boostrap-based graphical design. Therefore, they will use the same assets, images, css and JavaScript components.
2. Share the same licensing-based mechanism. An application service will be built where it will scan a file or database to get the number of licenses available for each app, thus granting or denying access to users. The only thing that varies is the name of the application instance itself.
3. Use AzureAD authentication.
4. Each must use the same authorization mechanism. A claims-based mechanism will be built to retrieve the claims from the database, given a user AAD account.
5. Each must share the same administration console.This console will be the one needed to populate user information and common catalogs.
6. A service will be built, to show toast notifications within the apps.
7. An email notification service will be built, to send emails to users when triggered by business rules.

And some other, less important features, but these are the core ones.

A first, perhaps naïve approach, was to create an ASP.NET Core 2 solution for each application, and implement the shared functionality in a sort-of Core assembly that can be shared by each app. However, while this could work for points 2 to 5, I'd still be repeating the graphical UI design for each app (basically, copying the wwwroot folder as well as the shared razor views five times). So, a change tomorrow in a CSS would have to be replicated five times.

Another approach would be to create a single ASP.NET Core 2 solution, implement the shared functionality and the UI, and then use the "areas" feature o ASP.NET Core 2, each area being a different app. The problem to this approach is shipping the app: if I have to install the five apps in a customer's server, no problem. If I have to install, say, only two apps, then I'd have to ship the five apps anyway and find a way to disable the other three apps.

So, I'd like to know if there is a feature in ASP.NET Core 2 for handling this type of scenarios, or alternatively, what are industry-standard architectural designs that could apply here.

In Windows Presentation Foundation with Unity, I can create a common shell, and then load modules in that shell, within the same shell window. So, using configuration files, I can add or remove modules as I see fit. What I'm looking is something similar in concept. I do not want to create five ASP.NET Core solutions and copy-paste the wwwroot folder and implement the same mechanisms of authorization, notification, email, etc., but rather, find a way to load the core, common features and then load additional features.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question seems quite broad.

Comment: You might want to talk about what exactly are the "shared functions" -- for example, if it is just a matter of changing the simple placeholders and text such as logo/brand/application names or configuration settings, then there is one solution such as using different app configuration files and seed data.

Comment: you may find my cloudscribe project interesting because it has a foundation and then optional features that layer on top of the foundation all using bootstrap. It also can use Azure Ad. I tackled a lot of the same kinds of problems you are talking about. Read the introduction here https://www.cloudscribe.com/docs/introduction and if it appeals then take a broader look at the docs section.

Comment: @Svek Thank you for your input, I did mention about these shared functions, but have since edited the post and added further detail.

Comment: @JoeAudette very interesting, I just read the introduction, it might be. I'll study it further and see if I can leverage the design. But it does look very nice. Thanks!

Comment: Microservices & SPA seems ideal fit: authn-autho, notif, email, lic are backend services (implement it using asp.net core web api), in Web: SPA seems best analogy for common shell you described in WPF (based on your experience/learning curve/time SPA could be implemented fully without .net dependencies using angularjs or other frameworks).